# Why my pda 180 bosch sander doesn't move?

Tags: tool-repair

My delta sander bosch pda 180 doesn't move. I opened it and I think i can group every part into two big groups: the one with the motor and the one with the sanding pad. I took out the part with the sanding pad and left inside the motor, i plugged it in and it spins. Then I put back the other part, closed everything and plugged it in and the sanding pad moves very little or not at all, the motor makes a burnt smell. I’ve checked all the bearings I can see and they are spinning, brushes seem ok too. Can you help me to repair it?

The motor seems to be good and it spins. When i try to sand something the tool doesn't sand.

Comment: I'm not sure how the internet can help you with this. Even with detailed pictures it would be hard to diagnose without being there. At the end of the day if the motor doesn't spin under any load it just needs servicing by someone who can hold it in their hands. This feels off-topic not because of the subject, but because, well, there isn't much anyone can do to help you from our end of the internet.

Comment: I suspect the brushes - they can fail while still looking good.  You may be able to clean them but don't try to start it with solvents in there.

Comment: @jdv, *"hard to diagnose without being there"* true enough here, but isn't this so often our lot in life? With a great many Qs, present and past, we're faced with exactly the same issue where we're somewhat guessing at the cause and viable solution(s) so a great many Answers are basically "You might try this......" suggestions at the end of the day.

Comment: @Graphus, sure but we are talking about a purely mechanical thing here, and not a simple mechanical thing. That is, I can't see a single answer being "best" for this, as at best we would need some back-and-forth diagnosis to build up the "work from the known to the unknown" tree. A reddit-type forum is probably just a better fit and would be more helpful to the OP.

Comment: How old is your sander and how much work has it done? Assume it's out of warranty? If it was bought quite recently and has done lots of work you might consider it as having done its work and it's time for a new one. Consumer-level Bosch products just aren't built to last any more — compared to their products of only ~20 years ago they've been noticeably cheapened (as have almost all similar products, including brands that have a generally better rep. including Makita).

Comment: That all being said, there are two major things that can be wrong: 1. the motor can't drive any load; 2. the motor force is unable to move through the drive train (such as it is) to the working surface, possible because that linkage is malfunctioning or stuck. Test which problem you have by testing if the motor turns at all under any load.